# AM/PM settings for UIDatePicker wrong

Tags: ios, uipickerview, uidatepicker

[image]I made a UIDatePicker a time picker, and set its time to 15:00. In some regions, such as America, it will show correctly in the wheel as 03:00 but instead of "PM", it shows "AM". Any thoughts on how to set it correctly?

CURRENT CODE:

```
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:_dateWithTime];
    comps.hour = 15;
    comps.minute = 0;

    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
    datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    datePicker.minimumDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(checkinDatePickerChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this resolves your problem, but instead of

`datePicker.minimumDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];`

there should be

`datePicker.date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];`